# OpenLDAP Server nested Group search string

Tags: openldap, groups, search, slapd

i got a small problem here regarding OpenLDAP. The problem is to search for the member of nested groups.
Lets say i have this construct:

- dn=domain,dn=local

  - ou=people

    - cn=marvyn (inetOrgPerson)
  - ou=department

    - cn=administration (groupOfNames)
  - ou=application

    - cn=jira (groupOfNames)

marvyn is member of administration.
administration is member of jira.
I want to authenticate against jira and check if marvyn is in it but marvyn is in administrations which is member of jira.
How do i need to search or build the search string to find out if marvyn is member of jira.

Thank you guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using 'alias' objects to consolidate groups into OU's.

This is the how to from openldap:
http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1111.html

(Note you can change the object type to ou from cn to forward to an whole ou.)

- dc=domain

  - ou=applications

    - ou=jira

      - cn=jira-specific-group
      - ou(ALIAS)=all-groups-from-**ou=groups,dc=domain**

        - *cn=sysadmin* (not really there; located at **ou=groups,dc=domain**)
        - *cn=development* (not really there; located at **ou=groups,dc=domain**)
  - ou=groups

    - cn=sysadmin
    - cn=development

Comment: If this solved the problem for you, then you should mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with a single search string. You have to write some code.

Comment: Could you provide an example?